# Unable to schedule an Event in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a scheduled event which would be triggered every day and delete a row based on a date.
Here is my code. But it's showing syntax error.

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`delete_expiredevents`
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY 
COMMENT 'Delete all Expired events in verify_email table'
DO

BEGIN
DECLARE dt TIMESTAMP(1);
DECLARE dtn TIMESTAMP(1);
SELECT v_requested_on 
INTO dt 
FROM verify_email 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;  
dtn = DATE_ADD(dt , INTERVAL 15 DAY);
DELETE FROM verify_email WHERE v_expire_on >=dtn;
END
```

Also, how do I enable `Events` in **MySQL workbench**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter first. Otherwise your command would get cut off at the first `;` which would make it incomplete

```
delimiter |    
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`delete_expiredevents`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
COMMENT 'Delete all Expired events in verify_email table'
DO
BEGIN
   DECLARE dt TIMESTAMP(1);
   DECLARE dtn TIMESTAMP(1);
   SELECT v_requested_on 
   INTO dt 
   FROM verify_email 
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;  
   set dtn = DATE_ADD(dt , INTERVAL 15 DAY);
   DELETE FROM verify_email WHERE v_expire_on >= dtn;
END |
delimiter ;
```

Also use `set` when assigning to a variable.

Also there is no event GUI in Workbench. You have to use commands to configure events.

Comment: How do I enable and view the events in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Btw, will I be able to backup the `events` as like backing up tables and stored procedures?

Comment: You can enable and disable events. To backup an event you can just save the creation code somewhere.